# WebDriver C# extension methods in Java

Tags: java, c#, selenium, webdriver

In C# I would write extension methods to add functionalities to IWebDriver and IWebElement.

Example:

```
public static IWebElement ClearAndSendKeys(this IWebElement e, string text)
{
    e.Clear();
    e.SendKeys(text);
}
```

I would use this later then like this:

```
txtUsername.ClearAndSendKeys("user123");
```

I've changed job recently and in the new company I am writing tests in Java. So far I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out the best way to at least get something close to what I was doing in C#. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support extension methods, period. You can create static methods instead:

```
ClearAndSendKeys(txtUsername, "user123");
```

(using static method imports)